# - 1996 Chevy G10 Intermittent Brake LIght / Speed Problems

Tags: electrical, brakes, chevrolet, abs, g10

I have a 96 Chevy G10 van with 14x,xxx miles. It has a 5.0 engine.

Recently, it has been given me a whole host of problems. However, I doubt they are all the result of a single issue. My largest concern is with a recent issue that appears related to the braking system.

I noticed the issue first about several weeks ago. I was pulling into a turning lane when the van appeared to pull/buck/surge and I believe the both the Brake and ABS light came on. As I was actually turning, this sympton repeated itself, though I cannot be positive both lights came on.

I had not been driving the van due to the issues it had been have having, but, after performing another repair, I decided to try and drive it again. This time, while I was doing ~70mph on the interstate, the van essentially repeated the symtpons noted in the preceding paragraph - it bucked/pulled/jumped (I am not sure how to describe it), the speedometer fluttered, and at least one brake light (either the normal or ABS) briefly came one.

Again, I have not been driving it, but I went to test drive this morning. This time, I did not even fully pull out before the issues started. This time, only the Brake light was on. The van seemed to have a great deal of trouble getting to any speed; eventually, it jumped/bucked, the light went off, and it seemed as if might actually be able to accelerate fine. However, I was not willing to drive it any more to find out.

The brake fluid level is just fine. I have had the pads replaced recently, and have not noticed any problems with stopping the vehicle. I am not sure if some electrical issue might be possible?

The vehicle has also stalled intermittently, has a hard time starting, and makes some noise (a whistling noise during low speeds, tapping while the van is warm at idle), but I have a feeling these are not related.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.